# How to update a custom property value modified by script?

Tags: python, scripting, properties

I have a custom property that controls two shape keys. When I type `bpy.context.object.pose.bones["Bone"]["prueba"] = 1.0` in the console, the value changes but does not affect the shape keys. If after that I click on the value slider of the property it updates the changes. What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to force a frame change to get it to update.

```
   bpy.context.scene.frame_current += 1
```

Comment: Set a frame with scene.frame_set(frame)  or use scene.update()